# HP UFT v14.00: Simulate keystroke

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I am trying to simulate keystroke that should create and then save a new record.
When i run the test, the UFT just run over the commands without performing any action or showing any error.

```
'to simulate keystrokes
Dim objKeys
Set objKeys = CreateObject("wscript.shell")

'Go to tab FB
Browser("Home:").Page("Home:").WebElement("tab_FB").Click

'go to FB list
Browser("Home:").Page("Home:").WebElement("FB_List").Click
Browser("My Feedback").Page("My Feedback").WebElement("WebElement").Click
wait 10

'Using keystroke to create new Record [CTRL+n]
objKeys.SendKeys "^({n})"

'Saving the new Record [CTRL+SHIFT+s]
Wait 2
objKeys.SendKeys "^(+({s}))"
wait 5

'Show new record id 
    fb = Browser("Home:").Page("Home:").Link("FB_Number").GetROProperty("innertext") 

MsgBox fb
```

Can some one suggest how to resolve this issue?

Comment: https://www.joecolantonio.com/2010/09/23/3-ways-to-use-keyboard-input-in-quicktest-professional-type-sendkeys-and-device-replay/

Comment: Do not perform any other actions when you try to run this script. If you  perform any other actions while running this script it will fail. Can you tell me ,  is It actually selecting the web element?

Comment: If i shut down the Firefox and then run the script it is working, but if i run couple scripts then nothing happens.